# set of natural numbers subset of the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The natural numbers are said to be a subset of the real numbers but how is this possible since in the set of natural numbers division is not allowed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What has division to do with subsethood?

Comment: Operations don't change the underlying set.  Subsethood only concerns members of the sets.

Comment: What does division have to do with subsets? {orange, apple, pear} is a subset of {banana, apple,orange, pineapple,pear} but division of fruit is not allowed.

Comment: Smell and hearing are a subset of the five senses, but you couldn't tell a red painted ball by them alone.

Answer (score 2):

Real numbers are basically all numbers, decimal, whole, negative, and positive except for imaginary numbers. They include both rational and irrational numbers. A more formal definition is any value that can represent a distance along a line (-ve and positive denoting direction).

Natural numbers are just whole positive numbers. Since whole positive numbers can represent a distance along a line, they are a subset of real numbers.

I really don't understand what division has to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

That the set of natural numbers is a subset of the set of real numbers just means that all natural numbers are also real numbers. You may be thinking of the term subfield, which is a subset that is a field with respect to the same operations as the larger set. Since the set of natural numbers has no multiplicative inverses (or additive for that matter), it is indeed not a subfield of the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A set $A$ is said to be a subset of a set $B$ if and only if every member of $A$ is a member of $B$.

Since every natural number is a real number, the set of natural numbers($\Bbb N$) is a subset of the set of real numbers($\Bbb R$). It should be clear from the definition that containment(subset) relationships have nothing to do with the possible binary operations defined on the set.

What you might be thinking of is a group, in which case the set of non-zero real numbers form a group under multiplication but the set of natural numbers do not form a subgroup because you cannot guarantee a multiplicative inverse for every element.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that, "in the set of natural numbers, division is not allowed". That's not entirely true. We can do lots of division with natural numbers, e.g., $6\div 2=3$. I think you mean that the set of natural numbers is not "closed under division". That's true. There are lots of division problems involving natural numbers whose solution is not a natural number.

The set of real numbers *is* closed under division, with the usual provision that we don't divide by $0$. The natural numbers $6$ and $5$ are also real numbers, since the naturals are a subset of the reals. Their quotient, $\frac65$, is another real number, one which is not a natural number. There is no problem here.

Being a subset of the real numbers doesn't mean retaining all of the closure properties of real numbers. It's like this: the prime numbers are a subset of the natural numbers, and even though the natural numbers are closed under addition, the prime numbers are not: $3+5=8$. Here, the sum of two primes equals a natural that is not a prime, just like we saw the quotient of two naturals can equal a real that is not a natural.

Comment: thank you for the comment the question came up when discussing Eulers formula eiπ + 1 = 0. Some of the participants said that the 1 in Eulers formula does not belong to the set of natural numbers and is different from the 1 of the set of real numbers. What is your opinion

Comment: I think I understand your question better now. You might want to see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525182/supposing-that-numbers-are-reducible-to-sets-how-would-one-go-about-reducing-a/2525208#2525208

Comment: Basically, the way we define complex numbers, in terms of sets, is very different from how we define reals, which is different from how we define naturals. The complex number $1$ is technically the ordered pair $(1,0)$, where both elements of the pair are real numbers. The real number $1$ is technically the set of all sequences of rational numbers converging to the rational number $1$. The rational number $1$ is technically the set of all ordered pairs $(z,z)$ where $z$ is any integer. The integer $1$ is technically the set of ordered pairs $(n+1,n)$ where $n$ is any natural number.... (cont)

Comment: ...and finally, the natural number $1$ is technically defined as the set containing the empty set. The thing is, we *identify* the natural number $1$ with the integer $1$, which we identify with the rational number $1$, which we identify with the real number $1$, which we identify with the complex number $1$. Nobody treats them as different objects, which is why we give them all the same name. When we're talking about the properties of the complex number $1$, or of the natural number $1$, then nothing about the differing set-theoretic definitions affects how they behave, arithmetically.

Comment: Since the distinction amounts to nothing, practically speaking, unless we're doing nothing but set theory, we all tend to ignore these distinctions, and simply assume that $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$. There is a subset of $\Bbb C$ that "looks just like" $\Bbb N$, so we just pretend it's $\Bbb N$. Mathematical objects are typically defined "up to isomorphism" anyway, so there's no harm done.